# Site doesn't show admin panel when i write http://localhost:8001/admin/

Tags: python, django

Site doesn't show admin panel. What should I do?

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin/
Raised by:  news.views.PageViews
```

With what it could be connected? I don't know what to do.

```
class PageViews(ListView):
    template_name = 'page.html'
    paginate_by = 8
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-datetime']
    model = Page
    paginate_orphans = 1

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = kwargs.get('slug')

        try:
            self.category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
        except Category.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Page.objects.filter(category=self.category)
```

My urls below:

```
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path("logout/", views.logout_request, name="logout"),
    path("login/", views.login_request, name="login"),
    path("profile/", views.account, name="account"),
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PageViews.as_view(), name='page'),
    path('robots.txt', views.robots_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
```

Comment: Please show your urls.

Comment: update, check please

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet that your url controller for PageViews is too broad and Django tries to execute PageViews with slag 'admin' instead of opening the admin site.

Please, note that it's just a wild guess - you question is very hard to answer. Read this before posting another one: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Seems like I was right overall. For a way to fix this behavior check other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Django checks URL patterns in order. Since "admin" would be valid as a slug, the URL matches against the PageViews pattern and that view is called.

The solution is to put the more specific URLs, in this case admin, at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the order of your URLs. Django tries them from top to bottom. What is happening is that Django is processing 'admin' as a slug and trying to find a url with a slug with admin.

Change your `urls.py` to something like this:

```
path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path("logout/", views.logout_request, name="logout"),
    path("login/", views.login_request, name="login"),
    path("profile/", views.account, name="account"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), #move your admin/ to here
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PageViews.as_view(), name='page'), #where your admin url is going to get 404ed
    path('robots.txt', views.robots_view),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
```